# R - identify row if previous x rows have equal or smaller values compared to each proceeding row

Tags: r

Further to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453106/r-identify-row-if-next-x-rows-have-equal-or-smaller-values-compared-to-each-pr), I'm now having to check for the previous x rows having decreasing (or staying the same) values.

I'm having trouble getting the behaviour I'd expect, i.e. the diffs from m1->m2,m2->m3,m3->m4 return a TRUE/FALSE in m4.  I think I have it oriented the right way round and I thought maybe the lag on the `filter` was the issue but I can't make the `amendedcheckfun` work as expected after fiddling with the inner\outer `rev`s, the order of the `diff` & `NA`, and the `rep` statement.

Can folk suggest an `amendedcheckfun` that would do the same as `checkfun` but in the opposite row direction?

```
library("plyr")
df<-data.frame(ID=1,Month=1:15,Bal=seq(from=500, to=220, by=-20))
df$Bal[6] <- 505
df$Bal[11] <- 505

origcheckfun <- function(x,n) {
  rev(filter(rev(c(diff(x) <= 0,NA)),rep(1,pmin(n,length(x)),sides=1))) == n  }

amendedcheckfun <- function(x,n) {
  rev(filter(c(diff(x) <= 0,NA),rep(1,pmin(n,length(x)),sides=1))) == n }

ddply(df,.(ID),transform,diff=c(diff(Bal) ,NA),check=checkfun(Bal,3), 
  check2=amendedcheckfun(Bal,3))
```

amendedcheckfun output in check2

```
   ID Month Bal diff check check2
1   1     1 500  -20    NA     NA
2   1     2 480  -20  TRUE     NA
3   1     3 460  -20  TRUE   TRUE  # check2 correct
4   1     4 440  -20 FALSE   TRUE
5   1     5 420   85 FALSE  FALSE  # check2 not correct - id=2:4 all decreases
6   1     6 505 -125 FALSE  FALSE
7   1     7 380  -20  TRUE  FALSE
8   1     8 360  -20  TRUE   TRUE  # check2 not correct - id=5 is increase
9   1     9 340  -20 FALSE   TRUE  # check2 correct
10  1    10 320  185 FALSE  FALSE  # check2 not correct - id=7:9 all decreases
11  1    11 505 -225 FALSE  FALSE
12  1    12 280  -20  TRUE  FALSE
13  1    13 260  -20  TRUE   TRUE
14  1    14 240  -20    NA   TRUE
15  1    15 220   NA    NA     NA  # check2 not correct - should show TRUE
```

ideal output

```
   ID Month Bal diff test
1   1     1 500  -20    NA
2   1     2 480  -20    NA
3   1     3 460  -20    NA
4   1     4 440  -20  TRUE
5   1     5 420   85  TRUE
6   1     6 505 -125 FALSE
7   1     7 380  -20 FALSE
8   1     8 360  -20 FALSE
9   1     9 340  -20  TRUE
10  1    10 320  185  TRUE
11  1    11 505 -225 FALSE
12  1    12 280  -20 FALSE
13  1    13 260  -20 FALSE
14  1    14 240  -20  TRUE
15  1    15 220   NA  TRUE
```

Comment: Why not simply use `checkfun` with the input in reverse order (e.g., `checkfun(rev(Bal),3)`)?

Comment: Neat idea, but that returns all FALSE values.  Perhaps I misunderstood? `ddply(df,.(ID),transform,diff=c(diff(Bal) ,NA),check=checkfun(Bal,3), 
      check2=amendedcheckfun(Bal,3),
      check3=checkfun(rev(Bal),3))`

Comment: It's more likely that I misunderstood what what you're looking for. Would this do what you're looking for: c(rep(NA, 2), head(origcheckfun(df$Bal,3), -2)). The result won't match what you expect but it relies on the check, which seems odd to me. Shouldn't the 1st, 6th and 11th values of check be TRUE?

Comment: I've added in an 'ideal' output which might make things a bit clearer for everyone.

Comment: In your description you mention that the transitions m1->m2,m2->m3,m3->m4 should return a TRUE/FALSE in m4. From the first 2 values of your ideal output I guess that if there are not enough data the value returned should be NA. So why is the third value of your ideal output TRUE and not NA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that should do what you want

```
amendedcheckfun <- function(x, n){
    c(rep(NA, n-1), sapply(n:length(x), function(i, x, n) {all(diff(x[(i-n+1):i]) <= 0)}, x=x, n=n))
}

ddply(df, .(ID), transform, diff = c(diff(Bal), NA), check2 = amendedcheckfun(Bal, 4))
```

Notice that here the second argument of the `amendedcheckfun` is 4, corresponding to the number of consecutive values to check.

The output with your example is

```
ID Month Bal diff check2
1   1     1 500  -20     NA
2   1     2 480  -20     NA
3   1     3 460  -20     NA
4   1     4 440  -20   TRUE
5   1     5 420   85   TRUE
6   1     6 505 -125  FALSE
7   1     7 380  -20  FALSE
8   1     8 360  -20  FALSE
9   1     9 340  -20   TRUE
10  1    10 320  185   TRUE
11  1    11 505 -225  FALSE
12  1    12 280  -20  FALSE
13  1    13 260  -20  FALSE
14  1    14 240  -20   TRUE
15  1    15 220   NA   TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to difficulties with differing numbers of observations per ID and the sapply not scaling well over 70k plus records, I chipped away at it until I came across the rollapply function from the package zoo.

It's still not astonishingly fast but:

```
newcheckfun<- function(x,n) {rollapply(x,n,min,fill = NA,partial=1,align="right")}

df<-ddply(df,.(ID),transform
          ,diffs=c(0,diff(Bal)<=0)
          ,movcheck=newcheckfun(c(0,diff(Bal)<=0),3))
```